# jQuery detecting screensize changes without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-orientation

I have a script that runs based on screensize using

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1024) {//script}
```

This works fine, but requires a refresh between changes, as this will be used on a mobile website I need to see if the orientation changes.

How can i get this to detect the screensize without refreshing?

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TjzFW/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1024) {    
        $('div').click(function() {
            $('p').slideToggle();
        });
    }
}).resize()
```

---

*Update:*

You can use `orientationchange` event:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', check);

function check() {
     if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1024) {    
            $('div').click(function() {
                $('p').slideToggle();
            });
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not produce the desired effect. Not only did it stop the script from running once the size is under 1024, it fired the toggle multiple times (on chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TjzFW/1/

Comment: I tried it, still no luck unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TjzFW/3/

Comment: Oh yeah... That might actually help.. :D

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Oh yeah, _Cannibal Corpse_! Rock on!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15704/discussion-between-kyle-sevenoaks-and-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

```
function calculateHeight(){ 
   //do some calculations

}

calculateHeight();

$(window).resize(function(){
    calculateHeight();  
});
```

This is your game. In `calculateHeight` you write you calculation code, and then run it once to make everything with right sizes. After that $(windows).resize(); is called every time when the window is resized so u can calculate again.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jQuery resize() method:
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: does this get called on a mobile orientation change?

Comment: nope it's called on window resize, if orientation change changes window size (what should be expected), handler should be fired.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.